# How can I convert all fields of each nested document (reviews) through all the collection?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, nested

I'm trying to convert the field "points" from String to Integer inside nested document "reviews". I have to do for all documents inside my collection.
[Mine collection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q01rC.png)

For now I tried this on MongoSH but didn't work:

```
    db.wines.find({
"reviews":{"$exists":true}}).forEach(function(data){
    for (var ii=0;ii<data.reviews.length;ii++) {
        db.wines.update(
        {
            "$set":{
                "reviews.$.points":
                parseInt(data.reviews[ii].points)
            }
        }
    );
}})
```

Anybody could tell me what is wrong? Thank you. How can I implement in Java also?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
db.wines.find({"reviews":{"$exists":true}}).forEach(function(data){
     data.reviews.forEach(function(review){
         review.points = parseInt(review.points)
     })
    db.wines.save(data)
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work...